# unable to select Xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to select some webelement on 
    "http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-new-zealand-2015/engine/match/743953.html". Here I want to select total runs scored by the player  and extras on first table except total runs. I have made below xpath but it is also taking total runs. may i know how to avoid "Total Runs"

```
//table[1][@class='batting-table innings']/tbody/tr/td[4]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total runs has class `total-wrap` in the `<tr>` tag. You can look for element without this class using `not`

```
//table[1][@class='batting-table innings']/tbody/tr[not(@class='total-wrap')]/td[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "Total Runs" always comes last, you can use predicate `[position() < last()]` to leave out the last `td` that would've been selected using the original XPath query :

```
(//table[1][@class='batting-table innings']/tbody/tr/td[4])[position() < last()]
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it is not working please have a look into a website once

Comment: @Ab123 are you sure you wrapped the entire initial XPath with `()` when you tried it? Works fine when tested in Firefox's FirePath for me... see [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lSoF.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
(//table[1][@class='batting-table innings']/tbody/tr/td[4])[position()!=last()]
```

I do not think it's good idea to compose such complex xpath is a good idea.
Mabey you can get the full list and get rid of last one:

```
result.pop()
```